# VS2012 Mstest finds NO tests in Release build of F# solution. How to fix?

Tags: f#, mstest, visual-studio-2012

I have a VS2012 solution with two F# projects targeting .NET 4.5. The project B is a **MSTest** unit test project for the project A. When building the Solution in **Debug** mode, the Test Explorer identifies **4 unit tests** that can be properly executed. But when at least one project is built in **Release** mode, than
**No test are found**!
One important detail is both projects are signed and appropriate InternalsVisibleTo attributes are applied (in debug mode it works).
I have Debug and Release -.testsettings, that are default except the execution timeouts.
What am I missing?

Comment: To clarify -- when you build both projects in `Debug` mode (by building the solution) the tests are found, but if you build *either* project in Release mode the tests aren't found? My first guess -- something is wrong with one (or both) of your project configurations in release mode. Some settings (like strong-name signing) are configuration-specific, so it's easy to forget to set them for both configurations.

Comment: @JackP. thanks a lot for the hint. The --keyfile flag was missing from Release config. Not clear, thought, how the build succedded then without the keyfile.

Comment: @JackP.: Appears you got the solution, respond to my answer and I will delete it once you add an answer.

Comment: Thanks Guvante -- I've added my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clarify -- when you build both projects in Debug mode (by building the solution) the tests are found, but if you build either project in Release mode the tests aren't found? My first guess -- something is wrong with one (or both) of your project configurations in release mode. Some settings (like strong-name signing) are configuration-specific, so it's easy to forget to set them for both configurations.

Comment: UDP: [<assembly: AssemblyKeyFile("Filename.snk")>] may be used instead of command line argument.

Answer (score 1):

To clarify -- when you build both projects in Debug mode (by building the solution) the tests are found, but if you build either project in Release mode the tests aren't found? My first guess -- something is wrong with one (or both) of your project configurations in release mode. Some settings (like strong-name signing) are configuration-specific, so it's easy to forget to set them for both configurations.

Solution by [Jack P.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12258029/vs2012-mstest-finds-no-tests-in-release-build-of-f-solution-how-to-fix#comment16446409_12258029)

Thanks a lot for the hint. The --keyfile flag was missing from Release config. Not clear, thought, how the build succedded then without the keyfile.